# unable to execute a query on a local DB in VS 2010

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I am working with a local DB created in Access which I added as a DataSource to my C# project.

Here is one of the tables of this database, table called `Session`:

```
(PK)sessionID   roomID      sessionDate     sessionTimeStart sessionTimeEnd
1ACMP2343       MB0302       05/08/2013          12:00 AM       14:00 PM
2ACMP2343       MB2031       05/05/2013          09:00 AM       11:00 PM
1ACMP3456       TRY223       15/05/2013          12:00 AM       13:00 PM
2ACMP3456       CMP200       01/05/2013          10:00 AM       13:00 PM
1ABIO3422       MB2031       05/08/2013          11:00 AM       13:00 PM
2ABIO3422       CMP200       01/04/2013          14:00 AM       16:00 PM
1ABIO2217       MB0302       12/05/2013          16:00 AM       18:00 PM
2ABIO2217       MB2031       03/05/2013          12:00 AM       14:00 PM
```

I have a form with `listbox` with the list of rooms used in DB, `dataGridView` and a `button`. I would like to write a query that will return today's sessions for the given `roomID`. The user selects value from the listbox, clicks the button, and the results should appear in the `dataGridView`

So if I would select room MB0302, the result should be:

```
1ACMP2343       MB0302       05/08/2013          12:00 AM       14:00 PM
```

(There is one more session with this room number on the list, but occurs on different date than today)

I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class RoomSelect : Form
{
    DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();
    public string RoomID;

    public RoomSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "MB0302":
                RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                roomQuery();
                break;
            case "MC1001":
                RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                roomQuery();
                break;
            case "MC3203":
                RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                roomQuery();
                break;
            case "MC3204":
                RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                roomQuery();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void roomQuery()
    {
        string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Kacper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";
        OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
        MyConn.Open();

        //SQL query that todays sessions for the given roomID
        string query = @"SELECT se.SessionID, se.RoomID, se.SessionDate, se.SessionTimeStart, se.SessionTimeEnd" +
           " FROM Session se " +
           " WHERE se.RoomID = @RoomID " +
           " AND se.SessionDate = Date() ";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn);
        command.Parameters.Add("RoomID", OleDbType.Char).Value = RoomID;

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(queryResult);
        if (queryResult.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No active sessions today for the given room number");
            MyConn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = queryResult;
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it and click on the button, I recieve an error on the line `adapter.Fill(queryResult);`

> *An unhandled exception of type `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` occurred in `System.Data.dll`*
>
> *Additional information: `IErrorInfo.GetDescription` failed with `E_FAIL`(0x80004005).*

I have tried to simplify the query, removing the parameter, but the result remains the same.

**EDIT:**

I have simplified my query to look like this: `string query = "SELECT * FROM [Session] ";`. This still does not produce any results, but the previous error has been replaced by 15 sec. freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting brackets on your columns:

```
string query = @"SELECT [se.SessionID], [se.SemesterA], [se.SemesterB], [se.RoomID], [se.SessionDate], [se.SessionTimeStart], [se.SessionTimeEnd]" + 
" FROM Session se " +
" WHERE [se.RoomID] = @RoomID " +
" AND [se.SessionDate] = Date() ";
```

Edit: Session is an access reserved word, and it won't like that. See a list of reserved words here: [Access Reserved Words List](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

Comment: Try using the same idea (brackets) without the Where clause and maybe just one column, or all of them by using *

Comment: string query = @"SELECT *" +
               " FROM Session " +
               " WHERE [se.RoomID] = @RoomID " +
               " AND [se.SessionDate] = Date() ";

This did not worked either...

Comment: Hmm, I think Session is a reserved word for Access. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx Try wrapping this word (Session) in brackets or this funny looking quote ` and try again...

Comment: I have updated my query to:

tring query = @"SELECT *" +
               " FROM [Session] " +
               " WHERE RoomID = @RoomID " +
               " AND SessionDate = Date() ";

No errors now, but still no results...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your [SessionDate] = DATE() clause for a test run, as the Dates returned by DATE() and [SessionDate] could be different date format.  (US vs European).  You may have to format the [SessionDate] column first, to match the form of DATE().  Or use a DATEDIFF function.  Anyway you can add DATE() to your select statement to see the two dates side by side and eyeball them in your results (when you get results by trimming WHERE clause to RoomID only) .... Obviously please follow other comments advice with [] around reserved words.  HTH  (I wanted to comment only - but reputation too low )

Comment: If the name [Session] is causing problems, created a VIEW / QUERY in Access with a new name and query that instead...